# Document Preview on RestApi

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I am using rest api to get base64 of document so as to use it instead of url. after writting my code well, the image cannot be displayed though I got the base64. Only the frame is displayed.

```
public IActionResult DocumentPreviewTest()
{

    string base64DataFromApi = "data:image/png;base64,77+9UE5HDQoaCgAAAA1JSERSAAAAZAAAAGQIAgAAAO+/ve+/vQIDAAAACXBIWXMAAA7vv70AAA7vv70B77+9Kw4bAAAX77+9SURBVHjvv73vv71dd1gUV9e/M0tV77+9IAEVC++/vWjvv71";

    try
    {

        string[] parts = base64DataFromApi.Split(",");
        if (parts.Length == 2)
        {
            string base64String = parts[1];

            byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);

            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
            {
                string contentType = parts[0].Split(':')[1].Split(';')[0];
                return File(memoryStream.ToArray(), contentType);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest("Invalid Base64 data format");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
    }

}
```

I placed breakpoint to check if it is a base64 and it is.